# Problem with directory spacing when copying files

Tags: solaris

I trying to copy a file from a directory to another directory in solaris.

DIR1="/u01/home files"
DIR2="/u01/other files"

cp $DIR1/test.txt  $DIR2

cp: cannot access /u01/home
cp: cannot access files.

How do i resolves this error other than renaming the DIR1 not to have spacing?

Comment: can you backslash escape the space?  e.g. /u01/home\ files/

Answer (score 1):

put quotes around your variables

```
cp "$DIR1/test.txt" "$DIR2"  # or try cp "$DIR1"/test.txt "$DIR2"
```

(not tested, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to a variable in the shell, as in `DIR1="/u01/home files"`, the quotes have special meaning, and are not actually assigned to the variable. So when you reference the variable with `$DIR1`, there are no spaces.

Try this instead:

```
cp "$DIR1/test.txt" "$DIR2"
```